# It is not possible to save and display the image using OpenCv / Tkinter / Python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am creating a graphical interface using Tkinter to be able to determine NDVI, I am using Opencv to make filters in vegetation. All good up to that point.
When calculating NDVI, the resulting image is black :(, you can not save it, but when you print the image you get the value of each pixel.

Code

```
def ndvi(self,*args):
        #self.res_guar esta en BGR

        self.res_guar = self.res_guar.astype('float')
        (self.r,self.g,self.b) = cv2.split(self.res_guar)

        #Calculo NDVI
        self.resta = cv2.subtract(self.r,self.b)
        self.suma = cv2.add(self.r,self.b)
        self.ndvi = cv2.divide(self.resta,self.suma)


        self.rows,self.cols,_ = self.res_guar.shape
        self.y = np.zeros((self.rows,self.cols,3),dtype=np.uint8)  # for output
        greenyellow = [4,255,173]
        yellow = [0,255,255]
        yellowred = [4,111,255]
        green = [0,255,0]
        blue = [255,0,0]
        red = [0,0,255]
        white = [255,255,255]
        black = [0,0,0]

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                k = self.ndvi[i,j]
                if 0.0 < k < 0.2 :
                    self.y[i,j] = yellowred
                    #print "Pintando AmarilloRojo"
                    break
                elif 0.2 < k < 0.4 :
                    self.y[i,j] = yellow
                    #print "Pintando Amarillo"
                    break
                elif 0.4 < k < 0.6 :
                    self.y[i,j] = greenyellow
                    #print "Pintando AmarilloVerde"
                    break               
                elif k > 0.6 :
                    self.y[i,j] = green
                    #print "Pintando Verde"
                    break                   
                else:
                    self.y[i,j] = black
                    #print "Negro"
                    break

        #Print Imagen resultante
        print(self.y)
        #Guardar Imagen
        cv2.imwrite('NDVI.jpg',self.y)
        #Mostrar Imagen
        ndvi = Image.fromarray(self.y,'RGB').resize((570,650), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # convierte a formato ImageTk 
        ndvi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ndvi)
        # Ajuste de la imagen de hsv a tk etiqueta de imagen
        self.original_img_lbl.configure(image=ndvi)
        # adding a reference to the image to Prevent python's garbage collection from deleting it
        #Anadiendo una referencia a la imagen para evitar que python garbage collection lo elimine
        self.original_img_lbl.image = ndvi
```

image Original
url=http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadepantallade2016-12-2310-08-43.php

Prosecution
url=http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadepantallade2016-12-2310-09-33.php

NDVI
url=http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadepantallade2016-12-2310-09-40.php

Print self.y

```
[[[  4 111 255]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  4 111 255]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  4 111 255]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 ..., 
 [[  4 255 173]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  4 255 173]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  4 255 173]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ..., 
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

NDVI image saved
url=http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/ndvi.php

Answer (score 1):

Take out all your `break` statements from your `if` statement. What happens is your `if` statement changes the value of one pixel, but then you `break` your for loop and no other pixels get written. Remove all your `break` statements and you should be fine.

Comment: Great, thaks
http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadepantallade2016-12-2312-25-39.php